# Getters and setters for UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimageview, setter, getter

In my `UIView` subclass' .h:

```
@interface MyView : UIView
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *imageView;
@end
```

I'm setting up the `UIImageView` on my `UIView` subclass like this (`init` method):

```
self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 0, 34, 34)];
self.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = CGRectGetWidth(imageView.frame) / 2.0f;
self.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
self.imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor someColor];
[self addSubview: self.imageView];
```

So, I can do `myView.imageView.image = [UIImage someImage]` and it sets the image on the `UIImageView` correctly. My problem comes when trying to clean up the code on my `UIView` subclass.

I'm trying to do this:

```
- (UIImageView *)imageView {
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 0, 34, 34)];
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = CGRectGetWidth(profilePhotoImageView.frame) / 2.0f;
    imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    return imageView;
}
```

and then from the `init` method do

`[self addSubView: [self imageView]];`

But when I do `myView.imageView.image = [UIImage someImage]` the image doesn't show on the UIImageView.

What am I forgetting?

Comment: Can you show the rest of your implementation of the `imageView` getter method?

Comment: Refer to my answer for how you need to change your method to fix the problem, based on your updated question.

Comment: must check if ivar is previously initilized or not... if not just create like if(!_imageView){_imageView = [UIImageView alloc] init];}

Comment: Thanks, @C_X! This pointed me in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your `imageView` getter method is getting the `UIImageView` instance already stored in the instance variable `_imageView`. Otherwise each time you call the `imageView` method, you're creating a new instance of a `UIImageView`, so you're not going to be setting the image on the instance that actually got added to your view.

So, here's how your `imageView` method should look:

```
- (UIImageView *) imageView {
    UIImageView *imageView = _imageView;
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = CGRectGetWidth(profilePhotoImageView.frame) / 2.0f;
    imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    return imageView;
}
```

Comment: So the instance variable should have been already initialized?

Comment: You could also move the code that initializes the `UIImageView` into your `imageView` getter method so it doesn't get initialized at all until it's needed. This would be lazy instantiation.

Comment: It's important to remember, if you do go for lazy instantiation, that you only create a new `UIImageView` if it hasn't already been created. So you would do a check, like `if (!_imageView)` before creating a new one and setting up its parameters.

Comment: Yep, that's the way I did it, and now everything is working and my class looks a lot cleaner :D

Answer (score 0):

When you name your method imageView, it overrides the getter for your property. So every time you call it, you're calling the method and creating a new UIImageView.

IE,

```
myView.imageView
```

and

```
[myView imageView]
```

both call the method you defined, which returns a new UIImageView, not the one you created in init.